# Definition of Conditional Entropy in Paper

Tags: entropy, information-theory, definition, mutual-information

I was reading this paper: [InfoGAN](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.03657v1.pdf).

On page 4, in the first 2 lines of equations, I was wondering why the conditional entropy

$$H(c|G(z,c) ) = -\mathbb{E}_{x \sim G(z,c)} [\mathbb{E}_{c' \sim P(c|x)} [\log P(c'|x]]$$

Is this nested expectation a standard definition for conditional entropy? I could not find a reference for this anywhere. Perhaps the fact that $G(z,c)$ is a distribution makes this definition necessary.

Reference of the paper linked above: Chen, Xi, et al. "InfoGAN: Interpretable Representation Learning by Information Maximizing Generative Adversarial Nets." arXiv preprint arXiv:1606.03657 (2016).

Comment: could you please provide the full reference of the paper in case your link dies?

Comment: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.03657v1.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a lot of letters going on in the equation you cite, so I'll use an equivalent expression involving just $X$ and $Y$, which we assume to be discrete r.v.'s.
$$
\begin{align*}
-\mathbb{E}_X \left[ \mathbb{E}_{Y|X} \left[ \log P(Y|X)\right]\right] & = -\mathbb{E}_X \left[\sum_{y \in \mathcal{Y}} P(y|X) \log P(y|X) \right] \\
& = -\sum_{x\in \mathcal{X}} P(x) \sum_{y \in \mathcal{Y}} P(y|x) \log P(y|x) \\
& = \sum_{x \in \mathcal{X}, y\in \mathcal{Y}} P(x,y) \log P(y|x) \\
& = H(Y | X).
\end{align*}
$$
To recover the equation in the paper, simply identify $Y$ with $c$ and $c'$, and $X$ with $x$ and $G(z,c)$.